# Gaussian derivative kernel for edge detection algorithm

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, edge-detection

I'm having a look to a marker detection algorithms and reading [this](https://infi.nl/nieuws/marker-detection-for-augmented-reality-applications/) they are using an one one-dimensional derivative of Gaussian kernel to get the gradient. They've got divided the screen in a small scan lines 5 pixels apart and then they operate the kernel in horizontal and vertical direction to compute the gradient, I'm wonder how it's done that, i.e:

The operation they've got is:

```
[ -3 -5 0 5 3] * A
```

I assume it is a horizontal derivative?

So what about the vertical one, is just matter of multiplying by the transpose like this?:

```
A * ([ -3 -5 0 5 3]^T)
```

For another side to compute the gradient direction they use the 3x3 Sobel kernels, but the scan line is 5x5, anyone know how is it done?

Comment: You can read here about convolutions with a Gaussian and Gaussian derivatives: http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22

Comment: Thanks, really good explanation, but I still don't see clear how to apply that to the above case, would be great to see an example of how the gradient is calculated with the 1d kernel...

Answer (score 2):

The convolution

```
[-3 -5 0 5 3] * A
```

is sort of an approximation to the [actual derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). Because `A` is sampled, we cannot know the true derivative. We need a discrete approximation. One common approach is the [finite difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), where one simply takes the difference between subsequent elements: `A[x+1,y]-A[x,y]`. This is what you get when you fill out the derivative limit equation in the discrete case. `Lim h->0` becomes `h=1`, there is no smaller spacing. This difference can be computed using a convolution:

```
[1  -1] * A
```

This operation yields the derivative at a location in between two pixels. To overcome that, the central difference can be used: `(A[x+1,y]-A[x-1,y])/2`, or in convolution form:

```
[1/2  0  -1/2] * A
```

Further improvements can be obtained by convolving with the [derivative of the Gaussian](http://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22). The Gaussian is some sort of optimum when it comes to smoothing (regularization) filters. Furthermore, the convolution has the property: `d/dx (A * G) = A * d/dx G`. That is, convolving an image with the derivative of a Gaussian is the same as the *true* derivative of the image smoothed by a Gaussian. You could write such a 1D convolution as:

```
[0.013  0.108  0.242  0.0  -0.242  -0.108  -0.013] * A
```

Note that it would be better to also convolve columns with a Gaussian, to keep things isotropic. But let's ignore that for the time being.

For some reason, folk in the Computer Vision community seem allergic to floating-point values (this is improving a lot recently, but there will always be those thinking it's cheaper to compute convolutions with integer values). So it seems that the page you linked, they replaced the actual derivative of Gaussian kernel with an integer-valued kernel that approximates it. This leads to `[3 5 0 -5 -3]`. They also managed to invert the values, leading to an operation that approximates `-d/dx`.

That they later use Gabor to determine the orientation shows further that they don't really know what they are doing, as Gabor is a poorer approximation to the true gradient than what you can do with Gaussian derivatives.

In short, if you want to compute derivatives, do as follows:

```
A * d/dx G(x) * G(y)
```

(with `G(x)` the 1D Gaussian as a function of `x`, i.e. a horizontal vector, and `G(y)` its transposed; and sampling `d/dx G(x)` directly, not sampling `G(x)` and computing its finite difference derivative).

To compute the derivative along the `y` axis, do the same but with the derivative of the `G(y)` kernel.

Practical implementation advice depends on your language. [Here is some advice when using MATLAB](http://www.crisluengo.net/archives/150). It probably translates well to other languages too.

Regarding the 5x5 scan line: I don't know what this means. I think they sub-sample the image in some way to improve performance. Fewer pixels = faster computing.

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for your answer and time, I had a look to your articles and they are quite helpful to understand better the theory behind but for the moment I'm trying to understand what they did which seems a bit confusing for me so far. I'm targeting an embedded system fpga based and better or wrong they've got an algorithm which works and it seems good approach when you have limited resources. For the moment I'd like to understand what they doing on the convolution process with that kernel and the scan line approach...